# Referencing the low of the entry candle

Tags: pine-script

I want to do is reference the low of the entry candle:

```
if (longCondition1)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop = low) //this refrences the low of the current candle ↓
//but i want it to be like *stop = entry candle's low*
```

I've come across this `strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index` but I don't know how to utilize it to get the `low`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, when you place an entry order, store the low price in a variable and use that variable for your stop loss calculations.

```
var float entry_low = 0.0
if (longCondition1)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    entry_low := low
strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop = entry_low)
```

Coming to your second question, by default, your orders will be executed on the next bar’s open. So that if the price is moving up and down too much, you would filter that out and enter a trade with a confirmed signal.

Comment: thank you, it seems to work well but i have some outlier exits where it would exit way above the entry price even tho i'm only using `stop`

Comment: Then we need to see your whole code. You can ask a new question for that. Please attach a couple of screenshots too so we can see what’s going on.

Comment: after some testing it seems to keep selling on the previous candle's low as long as the `strategy.entry` conditions are met on said candle, so the value keeps getting updated even though there is one open trade way before. (using `efault_qty_value=100`)

Comment: i put an `if` statement inside `if (longCondition1)` to check if there is a long position open using `strategy.position_size > 0`